# How to get a text of a row of a column in sqlite database in android programming?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I Want to get text of a row of a column in SQLite. For example I want to get text of tenth row in the column named `title`. In other word I want to get tenth row text of `title` column. How to do it? Please help me. thank-you.
Here is my sample code:

```
final SQLiteDatabase mydb = new 
MyDatabase(EndicActivity.this).getWritableDatabase();

final Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery("select * from conteudos", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `moveToPosition(9)`:

```
final SQLiteDatabase mydb = new MyDatabase(EndicActivity.this).getWritableDatabase();
final Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery("select * from conteudos", null);
String title = "";
if (c.getCount() >= 10) {
    c.moveToPosition(9);
    title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in your own query by using the table's Id key if you know/have it:

```
final Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery("select * from conteudos where id = " + idYouWant, null);
```

Or simply by using limit and offset as in:

```
final Cursor c = mydb.rawQuery("select * from conteudos limit 1 offset 9", null);
```

The code above will return you the tenth row, you can use it for the nth row you want.